# Increment year in pandas dataframe based on previous row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

If i have a pandas dataframe like the one below is there a way to automatically change the year so that if the date in a row is before the one in the previous row the year will increment. It seems like the solution might need to be recursive.

```
       old_value     new_value
0     2022-11-10    2022-11-10
1     2022-12-11    2022-12-11
2     2022-01-10    2023-01-10
3     2022-01-20    2023-01-20
4     2022-01-01    2024-01-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare difference of previous riows if less like `0` with cumulative sum for groups, then add years in list comprehension:

```
g = df['old_value'].diff().lt('0 min').cumsum()

df['new_value'] = [a + pd.DateOffset(years=y) for a, y in zip(df['old_value'], g)]
print (df)
   old_value  new_value
0 2022-11-10 2022-11-10
1 2022-12-11 2022-12-11
2 2022-01-10 2023-01-10
3 2022-01-20 2023-01-20
4 2022-01-01 2024-01-01
```

Another idea is use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for add years per groups in lambda function:

```
g = df['old_value'].diff().lt('0 min').cumsum()

f = lambda x: x + pd.DateOffset(years=x.name)
df['new_value'] = df.groupby(g)['old_value'].transform(f)
print (df)
   old_value  new_value
0 2022-11-10 2022-11-10
1 2022-12-11 2022-12-11
2 2022-01-10 2023-01-10
3 2022-01-20 2023-01-20
4 2022-01-01 2024-01-01
```